# Access weights / coefficients of multi output Linear Regression model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have trained a linear regression model to forecast in a multioutput fashion. This is a time series forecasting problem which estimates the next 12 months of demand based on a set of inputs. In the past - had I only been forecasting one output value - I would have simply called the following in order to access the beta coefficients of the model:

```
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, Y)
weights = pd.DataFrame(regression.coef_, X.columns, columns=['Coefficients'])
print(weights)
```

However, when I run this for a *multioutput* model, I get the error:

```
'MultiOutputRegressor' object has no attribute 'coef_'
```

**How can I access the coefficients of a multi-output linear model?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's [MultiOutputRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor.html) object, each estimator has it's own coef_. You can get the list of the estimators used for predictions by accessing attribute **estimators_**

```
m_lr=MultiOutputRegressor(LinearRegression())
m_lr.fit(X, Y)
...
for estimator in m_lr.estimators_:
    weights = pd.DataFrame(estimator.coef_, X.columns, columns=['Coefficients'])
```